# Get Checkboxlist selected lookup value and update the list using SPServices

Tags: jquery, spservices

I have a CheckBoxList in which there is a Lookup values. Now I need the selected values and update it to the Lookup column in the list using SPServices.
I tried the below code:

```
var selectedValues = [];
 $("[id*=chbxPAD] input:checked").each(function () {
        selectedValues.push($(this).next().html());
    });
 $().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    listName: "Requirements",
    ID: id,
    valuepairs: [
                 ["Request_x0020_Type", selectedValues]
                ],

    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        alert("Updated.");
        }
   });
```

Comment: If you do `alert(selectedValues);` what values are coming up?

Comment: only the selected text like if there is a value in CheckBoxList like "Test1, Test2, Test3" and if I have selected Test1 and Test2, 
then selectedValues = "Test1,Test2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint lookup consist of 2 parts: ID of the item in the list and the Value. You can't set lookup only by the value because they are not the unique and can be the same with another item in this list. You should specify ID of the selected element.

Comment: Thanks. I have done the same thing as you told. But still column doesnt gets updated

Comment: As I understand you try to update multi lookup column? If so, the format should be like: "ID_1;#Value_1;#ID_2;#Value_2". In your case, try to specify something like this: valuepairs: [["Request_x0020_Type", "1;#Test1;#2;#Test2"]],

Comment: Thanks.. :)
Its working.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup Column needs to be treated differently.

The value pair should be like

```
valuepairs: [
             ["Request_x0020_Type", ["1;#Test1","2;#Test2"]]
            ],
```

Where 1 & 2 are corresponding `ID` values of `Test1` and `Test2`.

Comment: var selectedValues='';
        $("[id*=chbxPAD] input:checked").each(function () {
            selectedValues+= $(this).val()+";#"+$(this).next().html()+",";
        });
        var chbPADValue = selectedValues.slice(0, -1);
        alert(chbPADValue);


I am getting value as 1;#Test1,2;#Test2
and then i am updating chbPADValue but still column doesnt get updating